# Launching super dev mode is giving exceptions

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

My application consists of both `GWT` and `Smartgwt`. Currently I am using `GWT 2.7` and `Smartgwt 5.0` versions. On launching of `superDevMode`, I am getting the below error.
Also, I have added `gwt.dev.jar`, `gwt.user.jar` and `gwt.codesvr.jar` in my `classpath`.

Not able to debug.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing difficulty in using Super Dev Mode for big application which is having dependency and also its taking 5 minute to launch the application in SDM.

Comment: @yogish Where's your gwt-dev.jar coming from? If you're using the SDK as downloaded from http://gwtproject.org then gwt-dev.jar should contain the `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor` class; if it comes from a Maven repository you need additional dependencies (JARs) in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. gwt-dev jar is not from GWT SDK, currently it is coming from maven repository. Then I added asm-5.0.3.jar to my debug configurations and it resolved the issue.

Comment: @Thomas:Why jars are differ from SDK to maven.What does it mean?

Comment: @mohammedsameen The goal is "ease of use". Transitive dependencies are not an issue with "managed dependencies" (using Maven, Gradle, Ivy, etc.) but a PITA when managing dependencies "by hand"; so the SDK has "fat jars" (and "fat jars" with "managed dependencies" are a PITA; we still have some bundled dependencies –Eclipse JDT, Jetty– in the JARs deployed to Central and that's not without headaches for some people)